# how to display a grid with clickable tiles in windows 8 app?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I want to display a tile based grid with each tile clikable in windows metro 8 app.this grid should be in the center of the screen with equal distance from 4sides.

Comment: Xaml or HTML?  Mark up is different for each.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using `GridView`.

Like what Jeff mentioned, the mark up would be different for XAML and HTML5. You can find more information regarding GridView here:

[Metro App - GridView and ListView (XAML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780650.aspx)

From the link, you can toggle to it's HTML equivalent, just in case you're using that platform.

Answer (score 1):

HTML and XAML examples below

CSS

```
.outergrid{
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
-ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}

.innergrid{
display: -ms-grid;
-ms-grid-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
-ms-grid-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
-ms-grid-column: 2;
-ms-grid-row: 2;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;}

<div class='outergrid'><div class='innergrid'/></div>
```

XAML

```
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```